# Sort Data in the Table

Tags: r

For example, now I get the table

```
   A B C
 A 0 4 1
 B 2 1 3
 C 5 9 6
```

I like to order the columns and rows by my own defined order, to achieve

```
   B A C
 B 1 2 3
 A 4 0 1
 C 9 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in base R. First we make the example data:

```
# make example data
df.text <- 'A B C
0 4 1
2 1 3
5 9 6'

df <- read.table(text = df.text, header = T)
rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:3]

  A B C
A 0 4 1
B 2 1 3
C 5 9 6
```

Then we simply re-order the columns and rows using a vector of named indices:

```
# re-order data
defined.order <- c('B', 'A', 'C')
df <- df[, defined.order]
df <- df[defined.order, ]

  B A C
B 1 2 3
A 4 0 1
C 9 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If the *defined order* is given as

```
defined_order <- c("B", "A", "C")
```

and the initial table is created by

```
library(data.table)
# create data first
dt <- fread("
id A B C
 A 0 4 1
 B 2 1 3
 C 5 9 6")
# note that row names are added as own id column
```

then you could achieve the desired result using `data.table` as follows:

```
# change column order
setcolorder(dt, c("id", defined_order))
# change row order
dt[order(defined_order)]
#    id B A C
# 1:  B 1 2 3
# 2:  A 4 0 1
# 3:  C 9 5 6
```